# Why is gdbserver not found when using the Linaro external toolchain in Buildroot?

Tags: debugging, gdb, embedded-linux, buildroot, gdbserver

I am using Buildroot 2018.02 for an IMX6 board and the Linaro external toochain 2017.11 based on GCC 2017.11 (GCC 7.2.1)

Now i am adding some debug tools such as gdbserver on the target.

Everything is OK if i use the option `"Build cross gdb for the host"` and selecting the gdb debugger version 7.11.x for the host along with the gdbserver (`BR2_PACKAGE_GDB_SERVER`) in the `"Target Packages > Debugging,.."` menu. There are also other version of gdb available in Buildroot such as 7.12.x and 8.0.x.

However, for an external toolchain the recommended way is : 
https://github.com/mbats/eclipse-buildroot-bundle/wiki/Tutorial-:-How-to-debug-a-remote-application-%3F which means to activate only the `"Copy gdb server to the Target"` option in Buildroot (although the post is a bit old)

I have noticed that the `BR2_TOOLCHAIN_EXTERNAL_LINARO_ARM` description says that Linaro gdb is based on gdb 8.0 so a newer version that the one i am using (7.11.x).

But when i do that, i have the following message on the target board :

```
# gdbserver
-sh: gdbserver: not found
```

despite the following :

```
# which gdbserver
/usr/bin/gdbserver
```

gdbserver binary is on the target.

How to fix this in Buildroot ?

Moreover i have two additional questions :

1. Does it really matter to have the Linaro toolchain gdb instead of
   the gdb 7.11.x that works "out of the box" in my case ?
2. If i don't use the Linaro gdb then should i use the gdb version
   8.0.x ( because the Linaro version is based on the 8.0 of GDB ) ?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: It could be a broken symlink, or gdbserver is a shellscript with an invalid shebang line. `ls- l /usr/bin/gdbserver` or `file /usr/bin/gdbserver` will probably help to debug this. Apart from that, does your external toolchain contain a gdbserver binary?

Comment: `ls -l` output is `-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root        822000 Dec 31  2018 /usr/bin/gdbserver` . This is not a shell script or  broken link. The package used by Buildroot is gcc-linaro-7.2.1-2017.11-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf.tar.xz and can be found here https://releases.linaro.org/components/toolchain/binaries/7.2-2017.11/arm-linux-gnueabihf/ . It contains a gdbserver binary and a cross-gdb.

Comment: Does typing `/usr/bin/gdbserver` result in an error message?

Comment: Yes it's the same error message

Comment: Try `file /usr/bin/gdbserver` or try `ldd` on it or work out the options for `readelf` - that error message can confusingly be triggered by finding a file that is ruled unexectuable, for example it is in the wrong format, claims to be for the wrong ABI or relies on a different dynamic linker.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The gdbserver binary in the Linaro 2017.11 toolchain is broken: it requests `/usr/lib/ld.so.1` as the program interpreter (see below), but that program interpreter doesn't exist.

You can try to create a symlink `/usr/lib/ld.so.1 -> /lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3` (add that to your filesystem overlay if it works). Alternatively, you can specify the program interpreter explicitly by putting it before the executable, i.e. `/lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3 /usr/bin/gdbserver`.

The "program interpreter" is a parameter of an ELF file that points to a program that is used to load the ELF file into memory and to start executing it. The main responsibility of the program interpreter is to find and load the dynamic libraries that the program needs. Thus, it is usually called the "dynamic library loader", or `ld.so`. It is built and installed together with the toolchain - specifically, the standard C library (glibc). When a program is linked, the linker will also set the program interpreter (it is copied from `libc.so`). Apparently Linaro did something really peculiar to end up with a wrong program interpreter in the `gdbserver` executable.

Comment: `/usr/lib/ld.so.1 -> /lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3` or `/lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3 /usr/bin/gdbserver` ends up in a segfault but i guess you are right  : the Linaro gdbserver is broken so i am afraid there is nothing i can do to fix this in Buildroot. But does it really matter if i use gdb 7.11 or 8.0 instead - and not the Linaro one ?

Comment: The statement "prefer to use the gdb/gdbserver that comes with the toolchain" is a kind of ancient lore. I don't know what was the reasoning behind that statement and if it is still valid. The gdb/gdbserver 7.11 or 8.0 built by Buildroot should work fine.

Comment: "When a program is linked, the linker will also set the program interpreter (it is copied from libc.so). " -- the parenthesized part is incorrect. Your answer would be better without it.

Answer (score 2):

> `# gdbserver`
> `-sh: gdbserver: not found`
>
> depsite the following :
>
> `# which gdbserver`
> `/usr/bin/gdbserver`

Most likely:

1. The `gdbserver` is a dynamically linked binary, and
2. The ELF *interpreter* that this binary is linked to use is not present on the target system.

Use `readelf -l /usr/bin/gdbserver | grep -i interpreter` to find out what runtime loader this `gdbserver` requires. Verify that that file is not present on the target. Copy it to the target and enjoy.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. Indeed the file was not present.